# time interval in function not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a(b integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$ 
declare 
   c integer;
   timevalue text;
begin

   timevalue = b::text || ' days';   -- build string like '7 days'
   select sum(value)
   into c
   from tablx
   where createdate between current_date - interval timevalue and current_date;

return c;
end;
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

function is simple... give summary of records which fits the date criteria.
for some reason it does not accept `current_date - interval timevalue`

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't specify a "dynamic" interval value. But as you always use the same unit, you can use:

```
select sum(value)
  into c
from tablx
where createdate between current_date - interval '1' day * b and current_date;
```

You can make that simpler, because you can subtract `b` directly from `current_date`

```
select sum(value)
  into c
from tablx
where createdate between current_date - b and current_date;
```

In an expression `date - integer` the integer value is the number of days.

For more details see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: `where createdate between current_date - b;` ? shouldn't between have 2 values?

Comment: `where createdate between current_date - interval '1' day * b;` doesn't work...  between needs to have two values.  I'm not quire following of why these two queries are the same.

Comment: @java: yes, I forgot the second condition for the `between`. They are the same because `current_date - 2` is the same as `current_date - interval '2' day`